# How to disable logs for whole cluster in gce

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Could it be possible for already created (Yarn/Hadoop) cluster to disable logging for all servers inside ?

I can't find anything like it. Is there anything in Dataproc or Compute Engine which can help me to disable the logs ?

Comment: Are you running a GKE cluster or a custom one using VM's in GCE ?

Comment: Cluster is created from Dataproc and type of cluster is Yarn/Hadoop and predefined settings for servers resources are using there, like 4 cpu 15gb ram and etc... so everything is from GCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With little help and suggestion from Google support, there is complete solution to skip logging for whole yarn/hadoop cluster.
That can be possible only when create new cluster from dataproc either by google cloud page or console.
Property which should to be set in cluster properties filed:
`dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable` to be `false`

[image: dataproc cluster properties]

More info at: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties

If you create cluster through console you can referral https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--properties and to use command like:

```
 gcloud.cmd --properties 'dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable=false'
```

Answer (score 2):

One easy way would be to create an [exclusion](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) in Stackdriver Logging that would prevent logs from that cluster from being ingested into Stackdriver.

Comment: if I am not mistaken there are some limit around 40 exclusions or something like that or maybe depend on the plan using

Comment: 50, as specified in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a resuorce based exclusion in Stacdriver - select a DataProc cluster you want and it will stop collecting any logs - hence bill you for that.

Go to [Logs Ingestion](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/logs/usage) page, select Exclusions and click blue button "create exclusion".

As a resource type select "Cloud Dataproc Cluster" > your_cluster_name > All cluster_uuid as shown below. Also - select "no limit" for time frame.
[image]

Fill the "Name" field on the right and again click blue button "Create Exlusion".

You can create up to [50 exclusion queries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exclusion-queries) in StackDriver.